# Connecting MAX VALUE with DYNAMIC ARRAY

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to connect two programms, one is with dynamic array, the second is about max value. The task of the programm I would like to be: User puts numbers, then theres is information about highest value.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <form>
        <div class="scd-item__qty">
          <input class="scd-item__qty_input" name="updates[]" value="5" id="awarie" />
        </div>
        <div class="scd-item__qty">
          <input class="scd-item__qty_input" name="updates[]" value="4" id="konserwacja" />
        </div>
        <div class="scd-item__qty">
          <input class="scd-item__qty_input" name="updates[]" value="3" id="mikroprzestoje" />
        </div>
        <script src="automatycznaTablica.js"></script>
      </form>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
const form = document.forms[0];
console.log(form);
const fc = Array.from(form.elements["updates[]"]);
console.log(fc);
const values = fc.map(input => Object.assign({}, {'input_value': input.value}));
console.log(values);
fc.forEach(input => input.oninput = update);

function update(e) {
  let index = fc.indexOf(this);
  values.forEach((obj, idx) => {
    if (idx === index) {
      obj["input_value"] = this.value;
    }
  });
  console.log(values);
}

//-part where it doesnt work ;/
var awarie = document.getElementById('awarie').value
var konserwacja = document.getElementById('konserwacja').value
var mikroprzestoje = document.getElementById('mikroprzestoje').value

var numbers = {awarie, konserwacja, mikroprzestoje}

const maxVal = Math.max(...Object.values(numbers))
const key = Object.keys(numbers).find(key => numbers[key] === maxVal)


document.write("Highest value is: ", key)
```

I tried to look for tips in the internet but without success :(

Comment: Why are you using `Object.assign()`? Just use `input => {'input_value': input.value}`

Comment: One thing I do see is that you're assigning input values to variables without using event listeners. This means they will always be `''`.